# AWS EC2 server crash - Cannot ssh login, ping fail

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2, crash

My ec2 server (in Singapore) runs over 1 year and it was fine until yesterday.

It is suddenly crashed (very likely): all applications run on that server are all stopped and I can't ssh login, ping also fail, even after I reboot it from AWS web console. In the web console, the server status is normal, shows "running" with a green light. But I just can't do anything on it!

It never happened in the past 15 months. And AWS doesn't allow me to request a technical support. What should I do?

I'm sure my security groups has setup correctly because I didn't change it at all.

Comment: Stackoverflow is for help with software development. You should consider asking this on [sf] or perhaps [webmasters.se].

Comment: do you have EBS volume attached or is it ephemeral disk ? if you have EBS, spin up another instance and attach your drive to this new instance, check all files are correct ssh folder etc ... you should find something that is not good